# Defining a list of values within a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-decorators, python-2.6

I know that this is a simple question, but I don't know what this is called and I can't find any details online...

Using **Python 2.6**, I simply want to be able to reference some predefined values that are defined in a class. I want the user to be able to reference them when using the class, as well as use these values within the class when validating parameters passed into functions of the class.

In my example, there are four different severity levels allowed. Currently, the user needs to use `Issue.severity_levels["critical"]` to retrieve the correct value for a critical issue. I would like them to be able to use `Issue.severity_levels.critical` instead. I also want to be able to use `if severity not in severity_levels:` to validate the severity parameter passed to a function.

My example:

```
class Issue:

    severity_levels = {"critical": "critical", "info": "info", "warning": "warning",
                       "error": "error"}

    @classmethod
    def page_out(description, ticket, details, severity="critical", custom=None):

        # Normalize severity
        severity = severity.lower()

        # Stop with error on a bad severity level
        if severity not in severity_levels:
            raise ValueError("Invalid severity")

        # do stuff...
```

What is this called? How do I implement it in Python 2.6? (Yes, that is very old, but that is the current environment we are working in. It is being replaced, but the new system is not ready yet.)

Comment: That's a _dictionary_, not a list. Are you saying you want to access a dictionary's values like attributes?

Comment: The current requirement is `Issue.severity_levels["critical"] ` because `severity_levels ` is a dictionary. To enable `Issue.severity_levels.critical` provide a method which manipulates the  `severity_levels ` dictionary as desired.

Comment: I want the class to have some groups of attributes defined (thank you) that users can reference when using the class. I also want to be able to access a group of attributes (like my "severity_levels" here) like a dictionary so I can validate that a parameter passed to a function is contained in the group of attributes.

Comment: For example, if a user codes x = Issues.severity_levels.critical , x would contain the string "critical" after executing that line of code.

I also want to be able to use if "critical" in Issues.severity_list: to see if "critical" is in my group of severity levels.

Comment: You might want to look into the `enum34` package on PyPi. It's a back port of the `enum` module that you will presumably get access to once the new system is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of `namedtuple` (according to the internet, this was introduced with Python 2.6), and class attributes (as far as I know, also available).

`namedtuple` works like a combination of a tuple and a dictionary (and also like a mini class). You can access elements by name using the dot notation, and also check for inclusion like you could with a regular tuple. You can even index them.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

# Define the namedtuple
Levels = namedtuple('Levels', ['critical', 'info', 'warning', 'error'])


class Issue:

    # Create the class attribute, an instance of the namedtuple defined above
    severity_levels = Levels('critical', 'info', 'warning', 'error') #=  {"critical": "critical", "info": "info", "warning": "warning", "error": "error"}
    
    @classmethod
    def page_out(description, ticket, details, severity="critical", custom=None):

        # Normalize severity
        severity = severity.lower()
        
        # Stop with error on a bad severity level
        if severity not in severity_levels:
            raise ValueError("Invalid severity")


'critical' in Issue.severity_levels  # True

'new' in Issue.severity_levels   # False

Issue.severity_levels.info   # 'info'

Issue.severity_levels[0]   # 'critical'
```

**Addendum**

To get the 'key' from the 'value' is a bit more convoluted:

```py
# using a list comprehension (I think this works in 2.6)
[k for k, v in Issue.severity_levels._asdict().items() if v == 'error']

# using a for loop
for k, v in Issue.severity_levels._asdict().items():
    if v == 'error':
        print(k)
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much!

One question... Why do you define Levels outside of the class? Would it not work if defined within the class?

Comment: Habit, I think; it seems to work the same if I move it inside the class, just above where it's actually called. That would mean it can't be accessed outside of the `Issue` class, but that doesn't sound like it's necessarily a problem. (I am a big fan of `namedtuple`s, so happy to spread the word! There is a reimplementation of them in the typing module (`from typing import NamedTuple`), that comes with slightly nicer syntax. I don't think this is available in 2.6, though. (I don't have an installation of that to check.)

Comment: One more question about this solution. How do you reverse the process... i.e. take the value and find it's "key"? I found the answer:  Use the _fields property. i.e. Issue.severity_levels._fields[Issue.severity_levels.index("critical")]

Comment: See the **Addendum** section. (But, yes. Looks like you found it.)